# How to catch PDO exception in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: pdo, laravel-4, exception

Can anyone help me on how to catch PDO exceptions in Laravel 4.2? I can catch the Fatal or Runtime exceptions using App::error and App::fatal in /app/start/global.php, but can't catch the PDO exception in any way. I don't want to tamper the Laravel base classes. I tried registering global exception handler but that didn't worked as well. Currently I've the following code in my global.php

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::view("errors.{$code}", array(), $code);
});

App::error(function(RuntimeException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::view("errors.500", array(), 500);
});

App::fatal(function($exception)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo '<center><h3>Sorry! Something is wrong with this request!</h3></center>';

    exit;
});

App::error(function(InvalidUserException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::view('errors.401', array(), 401);
});
```

How to add the PDOException block here or anywhere required?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that simply passing PDOException to your closure will catch the error like:

```
App::error(function(\PDOException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::view('errors.401', array(), 401);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, still showing the Laravel whoops screen. I think it's not coming to this point at all in global.php. Even I tried it at Router level, still no luck!

Comment: It works fine in my case, I just checked it out, I placed the code in ```global.php``` file and then in controller I wrote broken query and it printed the string I returned from error closure. Could you describe the place where you are calling this broken query ? It should not make any difference though as ```global.php``` file is fired even before routes are touched.

Comment: To be confirm, you are using Laravel 4.2 right? Actually I'm checking by changing the connection string. My main issue is I have a CRON server which pulls lots of data from API and puts into the database. And during that time sometimes the site connection to DB gets timed out and throws the PDO Exception. I'm trying to catch that.

Comment: Yes, I am using Laravel 4.2 and I don't see any possibility that this code could not work. Read about request lifecycle in Laravel and maybe you will get some better idea about why your code doesn't work http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle .

Comment: Okay, thank you @maksym-cierzniak, I will try to figure out what's the issue happening in my case and will post here.